# Elastic search cannot find JAVA_HOME

Tags: elasticsearch, java-home

I am trying to run elasticsearch.bat on my local windows machine after downloading the zip file on Windows. I get error:

```
could not find java; set JAVA_HOME or ensure java is in PATH
```

I already set JAVA_HOME and also put it in the PATH and I can type 'java' in my command line and see all the options. So why is elastic search not able to find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible solutions:

1. set your path to JDK package and not JRE package
2. Set your path up to JDK folder and not bin folder, example

   C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181

Comment: Cool, great. Happy to help